# Return an array of values and output each value sequentially

Tags: java, arrays, methods, return

Hey guys how do I output the two values separately and sequentially I returned from this method?

```
public static int[] getLargestAndSmallest (int[] numbers){      // semi-done
    int largest = numbers[0];
    int smallest = numbers[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        if (numbers[i] > largest){
            largest = numbers[i];
        } else if (numbers[i] <= smallest){
            smallest = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    return new int[] {largest,smallest};
```

Here is what is in main() method:

```
System.out.println(" The largest of the numbers is: " + getLargestAndSmallest(numbers));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(" The smallest of the number is: " + getLargestAndSmallest(numbers));
```

These sysout's give me something like this:  [I@55f96302  and  [I@3d4eac69, respectively. Please explain why and how to fix... thank you very much

Comment: Assign the result from `getLargestAndSmallest` to a variable and then simply reference the index like you would any normal array, `value[0]`...

Comment: Can you please demonstrate?

Comment: `int[] value = getLargestAndSmallest(numbers);` then use `System.out.println(" The largest of the numbers is: " + value[0]);` and `System.out.println(" The smallest of the numbers is: " + value[1]);`.  Take a look at the [Arrays Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) and [Returning a Value from a Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the value of an Array, which is an Object, hence calling the Array.toString() method. By default the toString() method will return "a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:

getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())" (from Javadoc)

So in your case you will probably need (avoiding calculating the array twice):

```
int[] largestSmallest = getLargestAndSmallest(numbers);
System.out.println("The largest of the number is: " + largestSmallest[0]);
System.out.println("The smallest of the number is: " + largestSmallest[1]);
```